# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorkbook$Factory

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use example: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/BusinessPlan.java

This is my dependencies list:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jsqlparser-snapshots</id>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and program:

```
/* ====================================================================
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
==================================================================== */

package org.apache.poi.ss.examples;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PrintSetup;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 * A business plan demo Usage: BusinessPlan -xls|xlsx
 *
 * @author Yegor Kozlov
 */
public class BusinessPlan {

    private static SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");

    private static final String[] titles = { "ID", "Project Name", "Owner", "Days", "Start", "End" };

    // sample data to fill the sheet.
    private static final String[][] data = {
        { "1.0", "Marketing Research Tactical Plan", "J. Dow", "70", "9-Jul", null, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x",
            "x", "x", "x", "x", "x" },
        null,
        { "1.1", "Scope Definition Phase", "J. Dow", "10", "9-Jul", null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null,
            null, null, null, null },
        { "1.1.1", "Define research objectives", "J. Dow", "3", "9-Jul", null, "x", null, null, null, null, null,
            null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.1.2", "Define research requirements", "S. Jones", "7", "10-Jul", null, "x", "x", null, null, null,
            null, null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.1.3", "Determine in-house resource or hire vendor", "J. Dow", "2", "15-Jul", null, "x", "x", null,
            null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
        null,
        { "1.2", "Vendor Selection Phase", "J. Dow", "19", "19-Jul", null, null, "x", "x", "x", "x", null, null,
            null, null, null, null },
        { "1.2.1", "Define vendor selection criteria", "J. Dow", "3", "19-Jul", null, null, "x", null, null, null,
            null, null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.2.2", "Develop vendor selection questionnaire", "S. Jones, T. Wates", "2", "22-Jul", null, null, "x",
            "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.2.3", "Develop Statement of Work", "S. Jones", "4", "26-Jul", null, null, null, "x", "x", null, null,
            null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.2.4", "Evaluate proposal", "J. Dow, S. Jones", "4", "2-Aug", null, null, null, null, "x", "x", null,
            null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.2.5", "Select vendor", "J. Dow", "1", "6-Aug", null, null, null, null, null, "x", null, null, null,
            null, null, null },
        null,
        { "1.3", "Research Phase", "G. Lee", "47", "9-Aug", null, null, null, null, null, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x",
            "x", "x" },
        { "1.3.1", "Develop market research information needs questionnaire", "G. Lee", "2", "9-Aug", null, null,
            null, null, null, "x", null, null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.3.2", "Interview marketing group for market research needs", "G. Lee", "2", "11-Aug", null, null, null,
            null, null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null },
        { "1.3.3", "Document information needs", "G. Lee, S. Jones", "1", "13-Aug", null, null, null, null, null,
            null, "x", null, null, null, null, null }, };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Workbook wb;

    if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-xls"))
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    else
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    Map<String, CellStyle> styles = createStyles(wb);

    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Business Plan");

    // turn off gridlines
    sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);
    sheet.setPrintGridlines(false);
    sheet.setFitToPage(true);
    sheet.setHorizontallyCenter(true);
    PrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
    printSetup.setLandscape(true);

    // the following three statements are required only for HSSF
    sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
    printSetup.setFitHeight((short) 1);
    printSetup.setFitWidth((short) 1);

    // the header row: centered text in 48pt font
    Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    headerRow.setHeightInPoints(12.75f);
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(titles[i]);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
    }
    // columns for 11 weeks starting from 9-Jul
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    calendar.setTime(fmt.parse("9-Jul"));
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(titles.length + i);
        cell.setCellValue(calendar);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header_date"));
        calendar.roll(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, true);
    }
    // freeze the first row
    sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);

    Row row;
    Cell cell;
    int rownum = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++, rownum++) {
        row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
        if (data[i] == null)
        continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        cell = row.createCell(j);
        String styleName;
        boolean isHeader = i == 0 || data[i - 1] == null;
        switch (j) {
        case 0:
            if (isHeader) {
            styleName = "cell_b";
            cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(data[i][j]));
            } else {
            styleName = "cell_normal";
            cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (isHeader) {
            styleName = i == 0 ? "cell_h" : "cell_bb";
            } else {
            styleName = "cell_indented";
            }
            cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
            break;
        case 2:
            styleName = isHeader ? "cell_b" : "cell_normal";
            cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
            break;
        case 3:
            styleName = isHeader ? "cell_b_centered" : "cell_normal_centered";
            cell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(data[i][j]));
            break;
        case 4: {
            calendar.setTime(fmt.parse(data[i][j]));
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            cell.setCellValue(calendar);
            styleName = isHeader ? "cell_b_date" : "cell_normal_date";
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            int r = rownum + 1;
            String fmla = "IF(AND(D" + r + ",E" + r + "),E" + r + "+D" + r + ",\"\")";
            cell.setCellFormula(fmla);
            styleName = isHeader ? "cell_bg" : "cell_g";
            break;
        }
        default:
            styleName = data[i][j] != null ? "cell_blue" : "cell_normal";
        }

        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get(styleName));
        }
    }

    // group rows for each phase, row numbers are 0-based
    sheet.groupRow(4, 6);
    sheet.groupRow(9, 13);
    sheet.groupRow(16, 18);

    // set column widths, the width is measured in units of 1/256th of a
    // character width
    sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 256 * 6);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 256 * 33);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 256 * 20);
    sheet.setZoom(75); // 75% scale

    // Write the output to a file
    String file = "businessplan.xls";
    if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook)
        file += "x";
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();

    wb.close();
    }

    /**
     * create a library of cell styles
     */
    private static Map<String, CellStyle> createStyles(Workbook wb) {
    Map<String, CellStyle> styles = new HashMap<String, CellStyle>();
    DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();

    CellStyle style;
    Font headerFont = wb.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFont(headerFont);
    styles.put("header", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFont(headerFont);
    style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
    styles.put("header_date", style);

    Font font1 = wb.createFont();
    font1.setBold(true);
    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    style.setFont(font1);
    styles.put("cell_b", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setFont(font1);
    styles.put("cell_b_centered", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    style.setFont(font1);
    style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
    styles.put("cell_b_date", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    style.setFont(font1);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
    styles.put("cell_g", style);

    Font font2 = wb.createFont();
    font2.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    font2.setBold(true);
    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    style.setFont(font2);
    styles.put("cell_bb", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    style.setFont(font1);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
    styles.put("cell_bg", style);

    Font font3 = wb.createFont();
    font3.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
    font3.setColor(IndexedColors.DARK_BLUE.getIndex());
    font3.setBold(true);
    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    style.setFont(font3);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    styles.put("cell_h", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    styles.put("cell_normal", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    styles.put("cell_normal_centered", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
    styles.put("cell_normal_date", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    style.setIndention((short) 1);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    styles.put("cell_indented", style);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    styles.put("cell_blue", style);

    return styles;
    }

    private static CellStyle createBorderedStyle(Workbook wb) {
    BorderStyle thin = BorderStyle.THIN;
    short black = IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex();

    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setBorderRight(thin);
    style.setRightBorderColor(black);
    style.setBorderBottom(thin);
    style.setBottomBorderColor(black);
    style.setBorderLeft(thin);
    style.setLeftBorderColor(black);
    style.setBorderTop(thin);
    style.setTopBorderColor(black);
    return style;
    }
}
```

But have exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorkbook$Factory
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:436)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:238)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:229)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.examples.BusinessPlan.main(BusinessPlan.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook$Factory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

How to avoid the above exception?

Comment: There's an [Apache POI FAQ entry on this topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025), what happens if you read and follow the advice there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

(Because Eclipse IDE don't point specific line missing dependency make hard to detect problem).

Reference: http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025

Comment: This is the reference to the ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar, which needs to be added to the classpath. Not to be confused with poi-ooxml-schemas-3.1X.jar which comes packaged with POI.

Answer (score 6):

***System couldn't find the* `poi-ooxml-schemas-xx.xx.jar`**,

Please add the library to your classpath.

Comment: Is this an answer....or where you trying to make a comment? If it is the first one, consider adding more details to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add jar from here and include it in your classpath: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoiooxmlschemas39jar.htm