# Trying to relocate poi jar getting a java class not found exception

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, apache-poi

I am submitting a spark job which uses poi 3.17 to read excel files but due to their being a rapid miner jar on the hadoop classpath which contains Poi 3.14 and there being some differences between the two versions I could not run my spark job successfully it fails half way through.

Here is my **spark submit**

```
    spark2-submit --class Digital--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 5G --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 20G --driver-cores 8 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=7G --conf 
--conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=60s --conf 
spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 --conf spark.yarn.queue=${queueName}  --conf 
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --jars alarming-v2.jar --files 
/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml --principal ${edgeUser}@${kerberos_realm} -- 
 keytab ${edgeUser}.keytab   BM-1.0.jar /tmp/digital ${start_date}
```

and  once I remove these rapid miners jars  from the cluster I can run the **spark submit successfully** .
Unfortunately we cannot remove the rapid jar from one of our clusters hence I am still getting the error on that cluster.

I use the getCellTypeEnum  which was added in 3.15

I tried relocating the conflicting libraries below like so.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
        <!-- <scope>compiled</scope> --> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> --> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
         <!--<scope>provided</scope>  -->
   </dependency>
```

**Relocation snippet**

```
 <relocation>
 <pattern>org.apache.poi</pattern>

  <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.poi</shadedPattern>
   </relocation>
```

Afterwards I am getting this error.

I think that it might only be shading the first poi dependency and not the other 2

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableStyles
```

Links to this stackoverflow page makes me think that I have an issue that this dependency is not being shaded
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorkbook$Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038041/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openxmlformats-schemas-spreadsheetml-x2006-m)

Update after doing some troubleshooting it seems not to be able to shade the implicit class below

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.ExternalLinkDocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.shaded.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.ExternalLinkDocument
    at org.shaded.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.ExternalLinkDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Is it possible to somehow shade the implicit class?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could add details of which spark mode you are using? If you are using yarn client mode, for instance, you will need to add the poi, xmlbeans and other necessary jar to the spark context so that spark will push the necessary jars from the driver to the executors. (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957696/what-is-use-of-method-addjar-in-spark)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I am using cluster mode I attached the spark submit and clarified that if there are no rapid miner jars this workflow will run successfully but for one of the clusters we cannot remove the rapid miner jars which contain an older version of poi library with some conflicting classes.

Comment: would it be feasible for you to modify your code to use poi 3.14 too? Or switch to https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/ which uses poi 3.17.

Comment: I was really hoping there would be a solution with shading the dependecy. Im not sure if using the spark-excel will work since it also depends on poi 3.17 but if I cant get a solution  I may need to rewrite the code as you suggested using poi 3.14.